# ExtJS 4.0.7 Ext.Draw drag and resize

Tags: drag-and-drop, resize, extjs4, draw

I add Ext.draw.Component inside grid cell as column renderer:

```
renderer: function(_value){
                var id = Ext.id();
                Ext.Function.defer(function(){
                    Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component', {
                        minWidth: width,
                        id: 'timer-' + id,
                        width: (_value * width),
                        style: {
                            position: 'absolute',
                            'z-index': '10000000',
                        },
                        height: 17,
                        renderTo: id,
                        resizable: {
                         dynamic: true,
                         pinned: true,
                         handles: 'w e',
                         widthIncrement: width,
                         },
                        gradients: [{
                            id: 'grad1',
                            angle: 270,
                            stops: {
                                0: {
                                    color: '#6594cf'
                                },
                                1: {
                                    color: '#c6d8ed'
                                },
                                99: {
                                    color: '#5f96db'
                                },
                                100: {
                                    color: '#6594cf'
                                }
                            }
                        }],
                        items: [{
                            type: 'rect',
                            fill: 'url(#grad1)',
                            width: '100%',
                            height: '100%',
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0
                        }],
                        draggable: {
                            constrain: false,
                        },
                        listeners: {
                        }
                    });
                }, 25);
                return '<div id="' + id + '" style="width:1000px;" class="timers" />';
            }
```

I need to know, how to drag this draw component only by x-axis. And I need name of listeners, whitch called on drag and on resize.
There is listner resize, but funciton return only new width and height (or I dont know some thing), I need to know, to whitch resizable handle was user pooled - left or right?